# how to pass return value of javascript function to a para tag on click of a button that actually calls this function?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript function:

```
function calculate(id1, id2)
{
var num1 = document.getElementById(id1).value;
var num2 = document.getElementById(id2).value;
return num1*num2;
}
```

that takes two parameters which are "id"s of HTML tags and then obtain the value present in the corresponding tags. The purpose of the function as you can see is to calculate product of two numbers and return the value.

The issue is that I have a button to call this function and pass args to it but I want to display the return value of function in a different para tag.

Here is code of Input tags, Button and Para tag:

```
<p>Enter two numbers to calculate their product</p>

First Number: <input type="number" id="FNum"><br>
Last Number: <input type="number" id="SNum"><br>

<br>

<button type="button" onClick=calculate("FNum","SNum")>Calculate</button>

<p id="para2">Hi</p>
```

I know I could write this in the calculate function:

```
document.getElementById("para2").innerHTML = num1*num2;
```

But I do not want to directly display the product in HTML para tag by changing its value from function but instead want to catch the return value from function and display it in para tag from the HTML page itself when the button that actually calls the function is clicked. To be more clear, I want to write the return value catching code of the function in the HTML code itself rather than in JS. I want to know if there is a way to do this and if so, how? I'm skeptical that this couldn't be done with the above particular function as it should be passed with two args every time if we try to use it but what if there is a function that does not take any parameter but return product of two numbers?

Thanks for your feedback on this :)

Comment: That's what Angular is built for, generating DOM on the fly. But it will always use JS. HTML is not a language, it's a markup, so it has no functions and can't calculate stuff with numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <button onclick='document.getElementById("para2").innerHTML =  calculate("FNum","SNum")'>Calculate</button>
```

Note that inline js makes your code incomprehensible.

Comment: Not to mention it's a bad practice.

Comment: This works for now, thank you very much. I will keep in mind that this is a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('para2').innerHTML = calculate('FNum','SNum')">Calculate</button>
```

However, I recommend you don't use inline event listeners:

```js
const fnum = document.getElementById('FNum');
const snum = document.getElementById('SNum');
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const para = document.getElementById('para2');

function calculate () {
  return fnum.value * snum.value;
}

button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  para.textContent = calculate();
});
```

```html
<p>Enter two numbers to calculate their product</p>

First Number: <input type="number" id="FNum"><br>
Last Number: <input type="number" id="SNum"><br>

<br>

<button>Calculate</button>

<p id="para2">Hi</p>
```

Take a look at [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I see that you have used no parameter calculate() function. Would the same be possible with my version of calculate() function?

Comment: As you can see, my solution calls `getElementById` only once for each element and stores the result in `fnum` ad `snum`. But yours would work, too.